# Modifying Variables within a Foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying build a parallel for-each loop which modifies two matrices. I create and initialize the matrices before starting the loop. Here is a dummy program which demonstrates how my code is supposed to work. The program executes without errors, but the matrices remain empty after the foreach loop is finished. NOTE: This is a simplified version of my code, NOT the actual code itself.

```
#Assume that I've loaded parallel and doParallel and that my computer has 2+ cores 
cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cluster)
a1 <- array(dim=c(9,9))
a2 <- array(dim=c(9,9))
numbers <- 1:18
foreach (i=1:9, .combine='c') %dopar%{
    a1[i,] = numbers[1:9]
    a2[i,] = numbers[10:18]
}
stopCluster(cluster)
```

Why doesn't this program populate the rows of a1 and a2?

EDIT: I couldn't find answers to my questions on any previous thread. There are similar threads for C# and Perl, but none which pertain to R.

Comment: I think it is just a typo mistake in this line `a2[i,] = numers[10:18]` , change `numers` to `numbers`.

Comment: @agstudy, I checked my program and there wasn't a typo. There was a typo in my post however, so thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use foreach to perform side effects of this sort.  The assignments in the loop are taking place in the worker processes and are purposely not sent back to the master.  You execute foreach for its return value, so if you want to generate two matrices, foreach should return a list of two matrices.

Here's an example that uses a combine function to construct multiple matrices from lists of rows that are produced by the workers:

```
rcomb <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  lapply(seq_along(args[[1]]), function(i)
         do.call('rbind', lapply(args, function(a) a[[i]])))
}

numbers <- 1:18
m <- foreach (i=1:9, .combine='rcomb', .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
    list(numbers[1:9], numbers[10:18])
}
```

Although `rcomb` is somewhat complicated, it can handle any number of matrices, and can be called with many task results which is important for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved this problem last month by using rbind in the foreach-loop.

Comment: @Xceptional could you provide your solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps. Couldn't test it, please pardon bugs.

```
 require(snowfall)

sfInit(cpus=2,parallel=TRUE)

a1 <- matrix(NA,ncol=9,nrow=0)
a2 <- matrix(NA,ncol=9,nrow=0)
numbers <- 1:18

a1 = rbind(a1,sfSapply(1:9,function(x) return(numbers[1:9]), numbers))
a2 = rbind(a2,sfSapply(1:9,function(x) return(numbers[10:18]), numbers))

sfStop()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use this. My actual code is a lot more complex and requires a for-each loop. There are numerous computations which take place before I even add any variables to a1 and a2.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap those computations in a function and then call it using SF(L/S)apply? Consider doing the computations within the cluster, get a list/vector as output and coerce it into the data structure outside.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried out your code and got the following error: "Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 2 nodes produced errors; first error: unused argument(s) (1:18)" I'm trying the other apply functions in "snow" and "parallel" but none of them seem to be working yet.