# How to fill in matrix inside of foreach loop?

Tags: r

I would like to fill in the matrix in inside of the parallel loop. 
When I call the function, it returns back me the empty matrix

I was wondering whether can someone help me with that.

```
Compute_TaskSimilarity<-function(X,...){
Task_similarity<-matrix(0,nrow=100,ncol=100)
foreach(i = 1:K, .combine = "cbind") %dopar% {

      for (j in (i + 1):(ncol(Task_similarity))) {

          Myvalue<- ComputeValue
         if (Myvalue!=0){

          TaskSimilarity[i, j] <- Myvalue

        } else{
          TaskSimilarity[i, j] <- 0.0
              }

          }
          return(TaskSimilarity)
        }
```

Comment: Please read the vignettes of the foreach package. What you are trying to do is not possible with %dopar%. You need to change your approach.

Comment: I believe your problem is solved in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/14903133/3104122

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this: create a `data.frame` of all combinations of indices, then apply over all combinations, then reshape into a matrix of the right size. (I added a simple multiplication as example for a more complex operation and used a smaller array of lenght 10):

```
indices <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10, each=10), y=rep(1:10, 10))

result <- foreach(i=1:nrow(indices)) %dopar% {
  # just an example for a more complex calculation
  indices$x[i] * indices$y[i]
}

result <- do.call(c, result)

dim(result) <- c(10, 10)
```